# how can i generate base64 string from local audio file

Tags: javascript, base64

how can i generate base64 string from local audio file?

i needed for send after via socket.io as base 64 string

i use angularjs actually

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

  .controller('DashCtrl', function () {

    var handleFileSelect = function (evt) {
      var file = evt.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      // this is the path of the file that i will have to send to the server
      // /android_asset/www/sounds/button-1.mp3

      reader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
        var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
        document.getElementById("base64textarea").value = btoa(binaryString);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
  });
```

Comment: just use the `.readAsDataURL()` FileReader method and chop off the MIME prefix

Comment: what if the MIME prefix?

Comment: I would suggest using buffer (`.readAsArrayBuffer()`) instead of base64 as the base64 is ~3x bigger in size, and socket.io v1 has support for binary data so...

Comment: btw, readAsBinaryString is deprecated